# Error 'SQLSTATE[22018]: with Date happens only some of the time

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax, pdo

I have this PDO Statement that's executed in an Ajax request, however it works about 75% of the time.

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid
> character value for cast specification: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11
> for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
> (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)' in
> C:\wamp\www\Timer\class.db.php:102
>
> 0 C:\wamp\www\Timer\class.db.php(102): PDOStatement->execute()
>
> 1 C:\wamp\www\Timer\insertRecord.php(16): Queries->insertNewOvenRecord('2017-07-20', 'PC-2', 'Rack_NR', '8', '9100501', 'PWW', '8:22:51', '0')
>
> 2 {main}

Here is my PDO Function

```
public function insertNewOvenRecord($date,$oven,$rack,$trayID,
                                    $material,$enteredBy,$start_time,
                                    $dblCure) 
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("EXECUTE STR_EnterNewOvenRecordSp ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");

    $stmt->bindParam(1,$date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$oven,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$rack,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$trayID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(5,$material,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(6,$enteredBy,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(7,$start_time,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(8,$dblCure,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Here is my php response

```
include('db_connect.php');
include('class.db.php');
$queries = new Queries($pdo);
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$oven = $_POST['oven'];
$rack = $_POST['rack'];
$tray = $_POST['tray'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$enteredBy = $_POST['enteredBy'];
$start_time = $_POST['time'];
$dblCure = $_POST['dblCure'];
try {
     $queries->insertNewOvenRecord($date,$oven,$rack,$tray,
                                   $item,$enteredBy,$start_time,
                                $dblCure);

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
```

I know that the problem lies with the date variable, however, I don't understand why it works some of the times, and it doesn't other times. Or what the root cause of the issues is. Can anyone help me out?

Column Types:

```
Date date 
end_time datetime 
enteredBy nvarchar(3) 
equipName nvarchar(30) 
material nvarchar(30) 
start_time datetime 
storageBayName nvarchar(30) 
sublevelID int
```

Comment: What is the column type in the database for start_time? Or all the columns for that matter. Can you post the table script?

Comment: What makes you so sure its the date that is the problem?

Comment: what does a `var_dump` or hex dump produce? maybe you've a (hidden) character being added on somewhere, this could be *anything*. Did you Google the error also? Many hits on this.

Comment: Well because the SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 0 <-.  From my understanding on the errors I've searched through, this specifies that the first bound parameter is where the cast specification error resides. The columns are as follow: 

Date date
end_time datetime
enteredBy nvarchar(3)
equipName nvarchar(30)
material nvarchar(30)
start_time datetime
storageBayName nvarchar(30)
sublevelID int

Comment: also,

When I execute this stored procedure in sql server with the same values that are shown above, the procedure executes without error.

Comment: start_time is datetime but you are passing no date, are you sure your problem is with the first field? Maybe try casting as string.

Comment: I'm passing it the time object, and in my stored procedure I combine the date and start_time fields. Which, like I said, executes properly 70% of the time. Like the statement works fine and then randomly it wont.

Comment: 70% of the time with the same data? Or different data?

Comment: The same data. I even tried executing the query by binding the values as strings inside the query and it still gives the same error. Could it have something to do with the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issue, however I still need to test it for a while to make sure it's working properly. I changed the datatype in sql server from time to nvarchar and then did my conversions on the string. Seems to work fine.

Comment: Not to be rude, but I hope you maybe learned something about asking for help today. You were given the answer 30+ minutes before you "found the issue" on your own, you could have spent that 30 minutes not wasting your time if you weren't being stubborn. Not only that, you claimed it as your own, which I hope you don't do to your co-workers. Glad you got it solved though.